# Simultaneous Touch on 2 Different Buttons triggers the Another Button (Middle One)

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, multi-touch

I have **5 buttons inside a LinearLayout** .

My problem is **simultaneous touch** on the **Left most & Right most button triggers the Middle** Button .

I have tried

```
android:splitMotionEvents="false"
android:windowEnableSplitTouch="false"
```

and unfortunately nothing works. What should i do ? .

My XML snippet is

```
     <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:splitMotionEvents="false"
        android:windowEnableSplitTouch="false" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/someText1"
            style="@style/ButtonStyle"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:onClick="someText1"
            android:text="someText1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/someText2"
            style="@style/ButtonStyle"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:onClick="someText2"
            android:text="someText2" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/someText3"
            style="@style/ButtonStyle"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:onClick="someText3"
            android:text="someText3" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/someText4"
            style="@style/ButtonStyle"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:onClick="someText4"
            android:text="someText4" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/someText5"
            style="@style/ButtonStyle"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:onClick="someText5"
            android:text="someText5" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/someText6"
            style="@style/ButtonStyle"
            android:onClick="someText6"
            android:text="someText6" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

If it have no direct solution , is there **any work-around** ?

Note : I am working on Android **JellyBean4.1.2**

*Lot of thanks in advance .*

Comment: Can u upload an APK for this?

Comment: how you fire *simultaneous touch* ?? Multi-finger touch ?

Comment: Yes.Sometimes it is very hard to re-generate the issue. Simultaneous touch (sometimes abnormal touch) using multi-fingers is required to re-generate  the issue.

Comment: can't you disable the touch of other controls when you touch the ONE? ie only one control is touchable at a time. As soon as the touch is complete, you can enable.

Comment: @SweetWisherヅ will you be please more elaborate ?

Comment: Whenever you get a touch event fired on any  button let's say button3, disable all other buttons. So that, any abnormal touch can;t fire your touch event. and at the end of touch event;s code.. before return statement, just re-enable all other buttons. Got it? @DonChakkappan

Comment: ok.I will try it & let you know @SweetWisherヅ

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce your bug. Are you using the emulator? Also, what is the style ButtonStyle?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if its works or not

Just Try to set OnClick listeners dynamically in your java code

like

```
button1.setOnCllickListener(onclicklistenerobject);
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that it's not possible to push several stock buttons (android.widget.button) at a time.

You can implement your own buttons or maybe detect multi touch on parent widget and check if touch position is on the button.